# Build is failing due to maven-sonar plugin issue when I run through VSTS Private agent

Tags: maven, sonarqube, azure-devops, maven-3

I am building maven project after that running sonar analysis but its failing with the below error.I am using java 8 ,Maven 3.0.5,Sonar cube 5.6.7 but I am not sure where should I make the configuration changes.Please help me out.

My VSTS Build tasks are Prepare analysis on sonar cube,Maven,Publish Analysis result.

**Error:**
Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project Product: With SonarQube server prior to 5.6, it is recommended to use the sonar-maven-plugin 3.3 -> [Help 1]
To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
C:\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin\mvn.bat failed with return code: 1
Could not retrieve code analysis results - Maven run failed.
Build failed.

Comment: You did not add the error details.

Comment: For using sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.. you should using Maven 3.3.9+ as far as I know..furthermore Maven 3.0.5 is a little bit old..better use more recent versions...Furthermore you are using a SonarQube instance which is older than the sonar-maven-plugin defines as minimum....